# Ethereum unimplemented feature

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.7.x

I am trying to compile this code:

```
contract C {
    struct s {
        string chan;
        string content;
    }
    s[] x = new s[](0);
}
```

And it lands me with a confusing compiler error:

```
Unimplemented feature:
/solidity/libsolidity/codegen/ArrayUtils.cpp(237): Throw in function solidity::frontend::ArrayUtils::copyArrayToStorage(const solidity::frontend::ArrayType&, const solidity::frontend::ArrayType&) const::<lambda(solidity::frontend::CompilerContext&)>
Dynamic exception type: boost::wrapexcept<solidity::langutil::UnimplementedFeatureError>
std::exception::what: Copying of type struct BlueSimple.s memory[] memory to storage not yet supported.
[solidity::util::tag_comment*] = Copying of type struct BlueSimple.s memory[] memory to storage not yet supported.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not implemented in solidity. If you want to initialize your struct, try the following code.

```
contract C {
    struct s {
        string chan;
        string content;
    }  
    s myStruct = s("YOUR TEXT", "YOUR TEXT");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, this isn't great. I actually need it to be an array. Oh well.